# Comment prononce-t-on la fin des verbes à la troisième personne du pluriel du passé simple?

Tags: prononciation, verbes, conjugaison

J'ai lu beaucoup de mots à la troisième personne du pluriel du passé simple mais je ne suis pas sûr de la prononciation.  Par exemple:

> allèrent, mangèrent, partirent, vinrent (venir), purent (pouvoir), durent (devoir).

Quelle est la prononciation IPA pour ces mots?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En général, la terminaison « èrent » se prononce `ɜʁ` quand il s'agit du passé simple. Suivant le même principe, « urent » se prononce `yʁ` et « inrent » se prononce `ɛ̃ʁ` dans ce cas.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to try [the wiktionnaire](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr), see [allèrent](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/all%C3%A8rent) for instance.

However, here they are :

```
/alɛʁ/
/mɑ̃ʒɛʁ/
/paʁtiʁ/
/vɛ̃ʁ/
/pyʁ/
/dyʁ/
```

Comment: Why'd you answer in English?

Comment: @BrennanVincent I'm not sure.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122398/is-it-standard-american-english-to-ever-contract-did-as-d