# Speaking the simple past tense out loud

Tags: grammaire, prononciation, temps-grammatical, ancien-français, passé-simple

When reading an ancient text—-I have a book of old French Fairy tales for kids-—how is one to pronounce out loud the historical past tense. Say, for example, the form -èrent in the 3rd P indicative, and so forth…

Comment: Does [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/494/11659) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comment prononce-t-on la fin des verbes à la troisième personne du pluriel du passé simple?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/494/comment-prononce-t-on-la-fin-des-verbes-%c3%a0-la-troisi%c3%a8me-personne-du-pluriel-du-pa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*-ai* /e/, *-as* /a/, *-a* /a/ are all as expected — like the forms of *avoir* they happen to resemble.

*-âmes* /am/, *-ûmes* /ym/, *-îmes* /im/ also follow the rules of standard pronunciation.

Slightly surprising is *-inmes* /ɛ̃m/ which manages to have a nasal consonant after a nasal vowel. (This is a similar case to the /m/ of *-isme* which strikes Anglophones as hard to pronounce.)

The *vous* endings are parallel to the *nous* ones with /t/ instead of /m/. And /ɛ̃t/ sounds much less strange than /ɛ̃m/ :)

*-èrent* /ɛʀ/, *-urent* /yʀ/, *-irent* /iʀ/, *-inrent* /ɛ̃ʀ/ ... Here [the answer anonymous2 linked to](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/494/11659) is correct, aside from the slightly different phonetic symbols Brennan chose.

You can also state a rule not only for the passé simple but for all tenses: **The *-ent* of a third person plural verb is never pronounced.** But it does count as vowel for the purposes of pronouncing what comes before it. So if you erased the *-nt* you would get a pronunciation that sounds like it looks.

Comment: Le -ai du passé simple peut aussi se prononcer [ɛ] chez certains locuteurs (mais d'autres considèrent que seul [e] est correct). La conjugaison *j'ai* de *avoir* est assez fluide entre [e] et [ɛ] chez beaucoup de locuteurs.